# Working with Image viewer webpart in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, image-viewer

I have inserted an Image viewer webpart in sharepoint page (say Page 1). Actually this page will be displayed by clickng on a Employee (link button) in onther page ( say Page 2) . From page 2 I can get Employee ID in querystring. So now I have to fill the image viewer webpart with an image based on the Employee ID. All the images stored in user profiles in sharepoint.

Can anybody give a solution how to pass parameter and get the imageurl from image viewer webpart?

Comment: use the querystring to pass the url.. why to trying to get the  imageurl from image viewer webpart?.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by creating a custom webpart and setting the value of image URL based on the employee id. Get the employee ID:

```
QueryParameterValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[0].ToString();
```

Create an object of imagewebpart:

```
protected Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ImageWebPart myImageWebPart = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ImageWebPart();
```

Set the URL value of the ImageWebPart here. Done